# Windows Security dialog window pops up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core-mvc, windows-10, smartcard

### Description of what the bug is

We are developing at Windows 10. Our backend is ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC

Windows Security dialog window pops up while I am developing an application through React. It is really annoying. We have to refresh page.

At first, this image is shown:
[image]

Then the above dialog window is replaced by the following dialog window. It requires smart card credentials:

[image]

### Settings of our application

`package.json` looks like this:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "7.14.3",
    "@babel/core": "7.14.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.14.2",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.14.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.13.13",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.13.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.1",
    "@types/node": "14.17.1",
    "@types/react": "17.0.8",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.5",
    "@types/webpack": "5.28.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.25.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.25.0",
    "agentkeepalive": "4.2.1",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.21.1",
    "babel-loader": "8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "5.2.6",
    "eslint": "7.27.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.23.2",
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "file-loader": "6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "5.3.1",
    "husky": "6.0.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "7.0.1",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "lint-staged": "11.0.0",
    "prettier": "2.3.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "4.13.0",
    "rimraf": "3.0.2",
    "style-loader": "2.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.3",
    "typescript": "4.3.2",
    "webpack": "5.38.1",
    "webpack-cli": "4.7.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.2",
    "webpack-merge": "5.7.3"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@hot-loader/react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "@svgr/cli": "6.2.1",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.170",
    "antd": "4.16.2",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "mobx": "6.3.2",
    "mobx-react": "7.2.0",
    "moment": "2.29.1",
    "process": "0.11.10",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-base-table": "1.12.0",
    "react-dnd": "14.0.2",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "14.0.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "6.2.1",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "2.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "9.2.3"
}
```

In addition, we are using proxy. The settings are applied from [this official React docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually).

Moreover, we are using [agentkeepalive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agentkeepalive).

Config of proxy file looks like this:

```
// development config
require('dotenv').config()
const package = require('../../package.json')
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const commonConfig = require('./common')
const agent = require('agentkeepalive')

module.exports = (webpackConfigEnv, argv) =>
    merge(commonConfig(argv), {
        mode: 'development',
        entry: [
            'react-hot-loader/patch', // activate HMR for React
            'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3030', 
            'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
            './index.tsx', // the entry point of our app
        ],
        devServer: {
            port: 3030,
            hot: true, // enable HMR on the server
            historyApiFallback: true,
            proxy: {
                '/api/*': {
                    target: argv.env.mock ? '' : process.env.API_URL,
                    secure: false,
                    changeOrigin: true,
                    agent: new agent({
                        maxSockets: 100,
                        keepAlive: true,
                        maxFreeSockets: 10,
                        keepAliveMsecs: 100000,
                        timeout: 6000000,
                        freeSocketTimeout: 90000, // free socket keepalive for 90 seconds
                    }),
                    onProxyRes: (proxyRes) => {
                        var key = 'www-authenticate'
                        proxyRes.headers[key] =
                            proxyRes.headers[key] && proxyRes.headers[key].split(',')
                    },
                },
            },
        },
        devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
        plugins: [
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(), // enable HMR globally
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env.appVersion': JSON.stringify(package.version),
                'process.env.isMockMode': JSON.stringify(argv?.env?.mock),
                'process.env.isDevelopment': true,
            }),
        ],
    })
```

### The current behavior

Windows Security dialog window sometimes pops up while I am developing an application through React. It is really annoying. We have to refresh page

### The expected behavior

Windows Security dialog window sometimes DOES NOT POP UP while we are developing an application through React.

### What we tried

We tried to set this option of [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), nevertheless the "Sign in" still  pops up

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

### UPDATE:

This is one of the URL that can return the 401 response with www-authenticate header-key:

```
 http://localhost:3030/api/notifications
```

Moreover, sometimes other methods can return 401 response. It is not always the same method return `401` response.

[image]

Comment: Please share the Network Analysis from the Dev Tools of your browser. Which URL returns the `401` response with `www-authenticate` header-key?

Comment: [Please check this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47811015/webpack-dev-server-hot-reloading-proxy-iis-express-with-windows-authentication)

Comment: So the authentication request is made by your `proxied` ASP.NET-`api`. It asks for `Negotiate` or `NTLM`. Can you share some further information about the authentication configuration of your ASP.NET app? Are you using IIS? Are you using Kerberos?

Comment: @Markus yeah, we are using IIS. In addition, it happens when we run Visual Studio locally.

Comment: @JasonPan thank for you comment, howeverI have the same configuration of `agentkeepalive`

Comment: Are you using Kerberos on your IIS for authentication?

Comment: @Markus I am sorry I do not know. I am running my application locally - I mean I run Visual Studio and then run React application. So it looks like we are using IIS Express. How can I know whether I use Kerberos?

Comment: Try to switch off any authentication: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7168308/18667225

Comment: @Markus sorry, however, I cannot do it. I should use authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Your `api` server based on IIS expects a valid authentication. It asks for `Negotiate` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55348267/18667225)), which is essentially Kerberos. Your browser accepts this but the negotiation fails, because you are trying to access the `api` url with a different base url than configured as SPN in IIS and because you are not using `https`.

There are at least two possibilties you can try:

1. Best for development is to mock all your calls to the `api` server. So no IIS-Server is called at all and no authentication is needed.
2. Try to switch off `Negotiate` in your development IIS just using `NTLM`.

Comment: sorry, but all options are not eligible to us