# How to apply createProxyMiddleware in webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, proxy, http-proxy-middleware

How to apply createProxyMiddleware in webpack?

I have a *webpack.config.js*  with default proxy:

```
// development config
require('dotenv').config()
const package = require('../../package.json')
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const commonConfig = require('./common')
const agent = require('agentkeepalive')

module.exports = (webpackConfigEnv, argv) =>
    merge(commonConfig(argv), {
        mode: 'development',
        entry: [
            'react-hot-loader/patch', // activate HMR for React
            'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3030', 
            'webpack/hot/only-dev-server', 
            './index.tsx', // the entry point of our app
        ],
        devServer: {
            port: 3030,
            hot: true, // enable HMR on the server
            historyApiFallback: true, 
            proxy: {
                '/api/*': {
                    target: 'http://foobar:8080/',
                    secure: false,
                    changeOrigin: true,
                    agent: new agent({
                        maxSockets: 100,
                        keepAlive: true,
                        maxFreeSockets: 10,
                        keepAliveMsecs: 100000,
                        timeout: 6000000,
                        freeSocketTimeout: 90000, // free socket keepalive for 90 seconds
                    }),
                    onProxyRes: (proxyRes) => {
                        var key = 'www-authenticate'
                        proxyRes.headers[key] =
                            proxyRes.headers[key] && proxyRes.headers[key].split(',')
                    },
                },
            },
        },
        // ... other code is omitted for the brevity
    })
```

Now I would like to use this [http-proxy-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware) because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73383232/windows-security-dialog-window-pops-up).

So I edit the above config to:

```
         // ... other code is omitted for the brevity
            proxy: createProxyMiddleware('/api/*', {
                target: 'http://foobar:8080/',
                secure: false,
                changeOrigin: true,
                agent: new agent({
                    maxSockets: 100,
                    keepAlive: true,
                    maxFreeSockets: 10,
                    keepAliveMsecs: 100000,
                    timeout: 6000000,
                    freeSocketTimeout: 90000, // free socket keepalive for 90 seconds
                }),
                onProxyRes: (proxyRes) => {
                    var key = 'www-authenticate'
                    proxyRes.headers[key] =
                        proxyRes.headers[key] && proxyRes.headers[key].split(',')
                },
            }),
        },
        // ... other code is omitted for the brevity
    })
```

However, when I try to build my application, it throws an error:

```
> [webpack-cli] webpack Dev Server Invalid Options

> options.proxy should be {Object|Array} (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy)
```

Please, tell me how can is it possible to aplly `createProxyMiddleware` for `proxy` in webpack config?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use the middleware instead of [Webpack's built-in proxy](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy)?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to do here. Do you want webpack's dev server to serve data with code that's served from a different server, or do you want to send API requests that are redirected to your API server?

Comment: Sorry for excessive comments, but I just want to mention you're getting the error because the proxy field is config for Webpack's own proxy, not some proxy you can manually set up.

Comment: @code I want to use middleware because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73383232/windows-security-dialog-window-pops-up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it's not possible to use custom middleware using Webpack's dev server. If you *need* the proxy bad enough, you can hook a custom Express server to Webpack and use middleware thus.

Make sure you additionally install [`express`](https://npmjs.com/package/express), [`webpack-dev-middleware`](https://npmjs.com/package/webpack-dev-middleware), and [`webpack-hot-middleware`](https://npmjs.com/package/webpack-hot-middleware) (if you still want HMR). Then create your server file with the following (like) contents:

```js
const express = require("express");
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const webpackHotMiddleware = require("webpack-hot-middleware");
const webpackDevMiddleware = require("webpack-dev-middleware");
const webpackConfig = require("./webpack.config"); // path to your `webpack.config.js`

const webpackCompiler = webpack(webpackConfig); // create webpack compiler with config

const app = express();
app.use(createProxyMiddleware(/* ... */));
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(webpackCompiler, {
  publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath, // provide the public path for the middleware
}));
// if you need HMR:
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(webpackCompiler));

// you need "*" if you're creating a SPA like if you're using react router
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(/* absolute path to index.html */);
});

app.listen(3030, () => console.log("Webpack running on express server"));
```

For the HMR to work, you need to slightly alter your `webpack.config.js`. Replace the second and third elements in `config.entry` with `"webpack-hot-middleware/client"`, then in `config.plugins` add `new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()`.

Now fire up your server with `node server.js` and treat [`http://localhost:3030`](http://localhost:3030) as your ordinary Webpack dev server <sub><s>and hope for the best</s></sub>.

*Remember that we're **only** doing this for development. We don't need webpack when running in prod.*

**Your `webpack.config.js` should end up something like:**

```js
// development config
require('dotenv').config()
const package = require('../../package.json')
const {
  merge
} = require('webpack-merge')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const commonConfig = require('./common')
const agent = require('agentkeepalive')

module.exports = (webpackConfigEnv, argv) =>
  merge(commonConfig(argv), {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: [
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client', // this powers our HMR
      'react-hot-loader/patch', // activate HMR for React'
      './index.tsx', // the entry point of our app
    ],
    devServer: {
      port: 3030,
      hot: true, // enable HMR on the server
      historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]
    // ... other code is omitted for the brevity
  })
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! Should I keep or delete file `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: @Learner keep. Notice the part about slightly changing your config file.

Comment: could you write, please, ax example of file? I really do not know how to edit this file correctly.

Comment: thank for your reply! I will check it later. I am sorry, but bounty has expired, however I marked your reply as an answer. Thank you!